# I can't make my timer on javascript to redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, performance

I'll try to be brief.

I know practically nothing about programming, I'm trying to learn by myself for a personal project.
I'm trying to do something like a timer which, when it reaches 0, redirects to another page. What I managed to build so far is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body>

<input type="text" id="txt">

<body onload="startCount()">

<script>
var c = 10; 
var t ; 
var timer_is_on = 0;

function timedCount() {   
document.getElementById("txt").value = c;   
c = c - 1;   
t = setTimeout(timedCount, 1000); 
}

function startCount() {   
if (!timer_is_on) {
    timer_is_on = 0;
    timedCount();   
}
}

</script>

</body> 
</html>
```

When I try it on chrome, it doesn't run or it instantly jumps to the other page.
If you could tell me what's wrong, or how to fix it, it would be wonderful.

Now, I just discover(?) that I lost the other part that redirects. I used this

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  location.replace("https://www.w3schools.com")
}
</script>
```

I don't know if I explained this correctly, but I appreciate the help!!

Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks everyone for the answers!! It's fixed now.

Comment: To redict page, set `window.location = ""https://www.w3schools.com"`

Comment: `timer_is_on` is never anything but 0, so `if (!timer_is_on) { ... }` is useless because 0 is always evaluated as false. You are not calling `myFunction` anywhere in your code, so it's not clear how your code would immediately redirect. Please [edit] your question to show how the code actually is.

Comment: @adnbsr `location.replace(url)` will also redirect, it just replaces the current URL in the browser history.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add your complete code including where you use you new function to do the actual redirect? And also why do you have 2 <body> elements in your html?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is update the value of timer in the input box every second until it reaches zero, and after that redirect to another URL.

This would do the needful:
(I have removed some unused code which is not required)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body>
    <input type="text" id="txt" />
    <body>

    <script>
        var timeLeft = 10;

        function timedCount() {
            document.getElementById("txt").value = timeLeft;
            if (timeLeft) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    timeLeft--;
                    timedCount();
                }, 1000);
            } else {
                window.location = 'https://w3schools.com';
            }
        }
        timedCount();
    </script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the timedCount check if the value of C is bigger than 0 and run setTimeout otherwise (smaller or equal 0) redirect

Also I think you meant to update timer_is_on to 1 here:

```
function startCount() {   
if (!timer_is_on) {
    timer_is_on = 0; //Shouldn't this be set to 1?
    timedCount();   
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could be one of the ways to do it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body>

<input type="text" id="txt">

<body onload="startCount()">

<script>
var c = 10; 
var t ; 
var timer_is_on = 0;

function timedCount() {   
  document.getElementById("txt").value = c;   
  c--;   
  t = setTimeout(timedCount, 1000);
  if(c <= 0) {
    window.location.href = "https://www.w3schools.com/";
  }
}

function startCount() {   
  if (!timer_is_on) {
      timedCount();   
  }
}

</script>

</body> 
</html>
```